# Cannot disable button in front-end for joomla 3.1.5?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.1

I'm having issues removing this button icon from my joomla site.

[image]

I went to the article options and selected Hide/no for all the options and yet this icon does not dissappear. The full site looks as follows.

[image]

Does anyone  know how to remove this icon? Can someone kindly assist?

When you click on the button you get the following options.

[image]

Comment: It show any subitem? Or just do not show options?

Comment: It shows an edit option. I uploaded a screen shot of it.

Comment: Well first, it is only going to show for those users who have edit rights. Keep that in mind, a guest will never see that unless you add other things to it such as print.

It's very hard to style that differently but it can be done using  a  layout override. YOu can see that the beez template does this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to turn off frontend 'edit module' button Joomla 3.2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865020/how-to-turn-off-frontend-edit-module-button-joomla-3-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

I was searched for a solution for the same issue you had when I found your question. The solution I took was a template overwrite, which removed the edit button for me. You need to change the com_content/article/default.php file and change the line:

```
$canEdit = $params->get('access-edit');
```

to

```
$canEdit = false;
```

A more detailed explanation can be found in the [source here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/solutions/joomla/145-how-do-i-turn-off-front-end-editing-in-a-joomla-3-x-template.html). This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

These links are all control in Global Configuration > Article Options. If you have them set to off, then you need to LOG OUT of the admin and then look at your page. They will be gone at that point.