# How to turn off frontend 'edit module' button Joomla 3.2.2?

Tags: joomla3.0

Does anyone know how to disable this functionality? (See pic below)

Additional Information: I'm using Rocket Theme's Metropolis template, so I'm not sure if Rocket Theme introduced this feature via updates or I got it through one of Joomla's updates.

The button is visible to registered users whenever they hover the mouse cursor over a module. When they click on it, it sends the user to the backend login screen. I do not want this feature at all.

[image: button that appears on top-right of each module position]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to **System** >> **Global Configuration**, and you will see an option called *Mouse-over edit icons for*, which you can simply set to *none*.

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked for the modules, but how about the articles? Any way to remove all edit links from the frontend?

Comment: @RaduDragomir - I suggest you ask a new question on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Just to be specific, this option is on the **Site** tab. (That tab may not necessarily be the tab shown when you use **System >> Global Configuration**.)

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still looking for this, it's now called **Inline Editing**. Located at **System > Global Configuration** on the **Site** tab.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, It matters now!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Inline Editing is now FrontEnd Editing in Joomla 4. Hopefully it stays put for a while.

Still located in /administrator/ -> Global Configuration -> Site tab. Just renamed.

[image]